# How to fix Supermicro AOC-SAS2LP-MV8 on Ubuntu 12.04 when attached drive doesn't show?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware

I have a Supermicro AOC-SAS2LP-MV8 controller card that I am trying to get to work on Ubuntu 12.04 server (x86_64).  The card is based on a Marvell 88SE9485. So far `lscpi` and `lshw` see the card but the one drive I have connected for testing isn't showing up.

`lsmod` doesn't have the apropriate kernel modules for this card listed. I can't determine where the kernel module is coming from. A search in `/lib/modules` doesn't have the kernel module either.

Note: I am trying to avoid re-building a kernel as this will go into a production machine.

Answer (score 1):

This patch seems to work for me on Ubuntu 13.10:

http://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2013/09/msg00184.html

```
Reported-by: Matt Taggart <taggart@debian.org>
Tested-by: Matt Taggart <taggart@debian.org>
Signed-off-by: Ben Hutchings <ben@decadent.org.uk>
---
 drivers/scsi/mvsas/mv_init.c | 9 +++++++++
 1 file changed, 9 insertions(+)

diff --git a/drivers/scsi/mvsas/mv_init.c b/drivers/scsi/mvsas/mv_init.c
index 7b7381d..83fa5f8 100644
--- a/drivers/scsi/mvsas/mv_init.c
+++ b/drivers/scsi/mvsas/mv_init.c
@@ -729,6 +729,15 @@ static struct pci_device_id mvs_pci_table[] = {
        .class_mask = 0,
        .driver_data    = chip_9485,
    },
+   {
+       .vendor     = PCI_VENDOR_ID_MARVELL_EXT,
+       .device     = 0x9485,
+       .subvendor  = PCI_ANY_ID,
+       .subdevice  = 0x9485,
+       .class      = 0,
+       .class_mask = 0,
+       .driver_data    = chip_9485,
+   },
    { PCI_VDEVICE(OCZ, 0x1021), chip_9485}, /* OCZ RevoDrive3 */
    { PCI_VDEVICE(OCZ, 0x1022), chip_9485}, /* OCZ RevoDrive3/zDriveR4 (exact model unknown) */
    { PCI_VDEVICE(OCZ, 0x1040), chip_9485}, /* OCZ RevoDrive3/zDriveR4 (exact model unknown) */
```

At least `lshw -c storage` sees the controller, and `fdisk -l` sees the attached HDD now. I'm not sure how stable it runs. Will report back if I run into any problems.

Comment: Any idea if the card is compatible out of the box on Ubuntu 16.04?